# best firefox plugin to check for valid html/css?

Tags: html

is there any recommended IE / Firefox / Chrome plugin that can check a html mockup design whether it is w3c compliant and also valid html/css?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/) checks to see if your code is w3c valid

Answer (score 0):

Visit this page [14 Free Tools To Validate Your HTML, CSS & RSS Feeds](http://www.sitepoint.com/14-free-tools-to-validate-your-html-css-rss-feeds/)